# React: get return value of a function inside the render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my render function I'm mapping a literatureTag array and check if the tag is equal to a projectTag. If the tag is equal to the projectTag, I want to store the color of the projectTag in a variable inside my render function. For doing this, I call a function inside render which compares tag and projectTag and then a color should get retured. This method works but the return value doesn't get passed to the variable inside the render function so that the variable inside render is undefined.

This is basically my code:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            projectTags: props.projectTags,
            literatureTags: props.literatureTags,
       }
//I've also tried this.getTagColors= this.getTagColors.bind(this) here but It's not working either
}  
getTagColors(tag){
        this.state.projectTags.map((projectTag) => {
            if (projectTag.tag_name === tag) {

                return projectTag.color

            }
        })
    }
render() {
        return (
 <CardBody>
         { this.state.literatureTags.map((tag) => {
           let colors = this.getTagColors(tag)
            console.log(colors)           //this console logs that colors is undefined
          return ( 
          <Badge style={{backgroundColor:colors}}>     //and this is not working because colors is 
                                                         //undefined
             {tag}</Badge>
          )})}
</CardBody>
)
```

Comment: `.map()` creates a new array based on an existing one. You probably want `find()` instead. You need something like `return this.state.projectTags.find(...).color;` (you might also want to create an array first before rendering, this time using `.map`, that basically turns `[tag1, tag2]` into `[{tag1, color1}, {tag2, color2}]`, that way you don't have lots of JS lines in your JSX) (( also, binding `this` is completely unrelated ))

Comment: The problem with my code is, that  getTagColor function doesn't get called from inside the render function. I don't know whats wrong. The main problem is not map, because if I call the getTagColor e.g. from the componentDidMount function, I'll get the correct result

Comment: I doubt that, because in the code you posted, `getTagColors()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: oh sorry,  you're right. I still had the code from the below answer inside the getTagColors function. But with the code from below it's still not working, because somehow the getTagColors method doesn't get called from inside the render

Comment: Here's working example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-northcutt-6hxnb?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Inside `getTagColors` you are using the `map()` method, and the `return` statement is inside of it. But, the `return` statement inside the `map()` method does not make `getTagColors` to return a value, but it exit from the current iteration of `map()`.

To recap, `map()` method creates a new array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Try to use a simple `for` loop:

```
for (let i=0; i<this.state.projectTags.length; i++) {
    if (this.state.projectTags[i].name === tag) {
        return projectTag[i].color;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is still not working. It's the same problem as I had before. It seems like the getTagColor function doesn't get called in the render function. If I try to console log anything in the getTagColor function it doesn't get console logged only if I call this method from an other function.

Comment: so it works if I delete the getTagColor function and put your code in the render function instead of calling the getTagColor function there.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're using the class component instead of hook (I'm pretty sure because of `this.state`). In that case, you also need to write `this.getTagColors = this.getTagColors.bind(this)`, and then in the `render()` method you call it using `this.getTagColors`.